# How to block drivers built-into Kernel, i.e. drivers who are not a module

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, modprobe

I configured and compiled Linux kernel with `nouveau` driver built-into kernel, i.e. with `<*>` as opposed to `<M>` when doing `make menuconfig` inside Linux kernel source directory.

Now, I intend to use another driver rather than `nouveau`. If `nouveau` was a module, I would add a line like `blacklist nouveau` inside `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

What should I do now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also temporarily blacklist them on the grub command line (linux line) when you boot with the syntax

```
module_to_blacklist.blacklist=yes
```

OR

```
modprobe.blacklist=module_to_blacklist
```

You need to modify the grub,cfg to make the changes permanent.

**Mind you, this solution will not work for few modules**

Comment: Which modules does it not work for, for example? What is the reason? E.g. in particular does not seem to work for `i8042`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心法轮功六四事件 it seems xhci_hcd is hard to get rid of this way.

Answer (score 17):

Not many people know about this, but there absolutely is a way to blacklist a driver built into the kernel.

First and foremost, you should run `lsmod | grep <driver_name>`.  If you don't see any results, congratulations - your driver is built directly into the kernel and the normal way of blacklisting it isn't going to work.  Instead, you'll need to blacklist your driver's initialization function instead.  To do this, you'll need to add `initcall_blacklist=<driver_init>` as a kernel boot option where *driver_init* is the driver initialization function - you'll have to look through your kernel's sources to figure out what name needs to be used.  As a concrete example, `initcall_blacklist=vmd_drv_init` used as a boot option prevents Intel's Volume Management Device driver from loading and binding to an active Volume Management Device controller.

Comment: One can also look for the function names in `System.map`. I did it like this `fgrep elants /boot/System.map-5.8.0-23-generic | fgrep init` for solving https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.6/+bug/1900254/comments/6

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. FWIW, another example, for the compiled-in `rtc_cmos` driver, blocking it with `initcall_blacklist=add_rtc_cmos` works great while `rtc_cmos.blacklist=yes` is ignored.